# GameObject.Find returning a null value in Xcode but not in Unity3D

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I thought I'd just finished an app, however when I build for iOS, there is a certain section that is returning a

> "NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required."

Here is the Xcode error:

```
NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required.
  at nextSetAmount.nextButtonCelestials (Boolean onOff) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at celestialDialogueInstantiator.setActive (Int32 indexToTurnOn) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchPress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData pointerEvent, Boolean pressed, Boolean released) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchEvents () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.Process () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
 
(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required.
  at audioManagerCreate.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

and here are the respective scripts that it's talking about:

**nextSetAmount**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class nextSetAmount : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject slider;
    public GameObject dialogueManager;
    public GameObject celestialManager;
    public GameObject audioManager;
    public GameObject celestialObject;
    
    // Use this for initialization
    public void nextButtonDialogue (bool onOff) {

        if(onOff == true)
        {
            dialogueManager.GetComponent<celestialDialogueInstantiator>().makeDialogue(Mathf.RoundToInt(slider.GetComponent<Slider>().value));
        }
    }

    public void nextButtonCelestials (bool onOff) {
        if(onOff == true)
        {
            audioManager.SetActive(true);
            AudioListener.pause = true;
            

            for(int i = 0; i < slider.GetComponent<Slider>().value; i++)
            {
                Transform celestialDialogue = GameObject.Find("celestialDialogue"+i).gameObject.transform;

                string celestialName = celestialDialogue.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>().text;
                float celestialBodyDistance = celestialDialogue.GetChild(4).GetComponent<Slider>().value;
                float celestialOrbitalFrequency = celestialDialogue.GetChild(6).GetComponent<Slider>().value;
                float celestialRotationalFrequency = celestialDialogue.GetChild(8).GetComponent<Slider>().value;
                float celestialBodyDiameter = celestialDialogue.GetChild(10).GetComponent<Slider>().value;
                float celestialBodyTemperature = celestialDialogue.GetChild(12).GetComponent<Slider>().value;

                // Instantiate celestialObject prefab
                var instantiatedCelestial = Instantiate(celestialObject, new Vector3(0,0,0),Quaternion.identity);
                // Define properties script for ease of code
                var celProps = instantiatedCelestial.GetComponent<celestialProperties>();
                // Set name of instantiated prefab
                instantiatedCelestial.gameObject.name = ("celestialObject"+i);
                // Set parent of instantiated prefab
                instantiatedCelestial.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("celestialManager").transform);

                // Randomise properties of the instantiated celestialObject prefab
                celProps.celestialName = celestialName;
                celProps.celestialID = i;
                // Set distance from centre as i (celestialObject number) + a float value. This ensures that 0 is closest, and x where x = amountOfCelestials is the furthest.
                celProps.celestialBodyDistance = celestialBodyDistance;
                celProps.celestialOrbitFrequency = celestialOrbitalFrequency;
                celProps.celestialRotationalFrequency = celestialRotationalFrequency;
                celProps.celestialBodyDiameter = celestialBodyDiameter;
                celProps.celestialBodyTemperature = celestialBodyTemperature;
                celProps.celestialOrbitAxis = new Vector3(0,1,0);

                // Store initial values for these two so that scaling doesn't multiply by itself
                celProps.celestialInitOrbitFrequency = celProps.celestialOrbitFrequency;
                celProps.celestialInitRotationalFrequency = celProps.celestialRotationalFrequency;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**celestialDialogueInstantiator**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;

public class celestialDialogueInstantiator : MonoBehaviour {

    // Define prefab to instantiate
    public GameObject celestialDialogue;
    public GameObject systemNameCreate;
    public GameObject parent;
    public int dialogueID;
    public GameObject slider;
    public GameObject[] celestialObjects;

    // Use this for instantiation
    public void makeDialogue (int sliderValue) 
    {
        // For loop that instantiates x amount of dialogues where x = argument.
        for(int i = 0; i < sliderValue; i++)
        {   
            
            var instantiatedDialogue = Instantiate(celestialDialogue,transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            instantiatedDialogue.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("createDialogue").gameObject.transform, false);
            instantiatedDialogue.SetActive(false);
            instantiatedDialogue.name = "celestialDialogue"+i;  
            instantiatedDialogue.GetComponent<dialogueID>().ID = i;

            if (i == 0)
            {
                instantiatedDialogue.SetActive(true);
            }       
        }
    }

    public void setActive(int indexToTurnOn)
    {
        // Turn on next dialogue
        if(indexToTurnOn != slider.GetComponent<Slider>().value)
        {
            GameObject.Find("createDialogue").gameObject.transform.GetChild(indexToTurnOn).gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            GameObject.Find("createDialogue").gameObject.transform.GetChild(1+indexToTurnOn).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        
        // When the last next button is pressed.
        else
        {
            
            // Set active createCelestials GUI panel
            Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<GameObject>().FirstOrDefault(g=>g.CompareTag("Finish")).gameObject.SetActive(true);
            GameObject.Find("System Title").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = GameObject.Find("dialogueManager").GetComponent<celestialDialogueInstantiator>().systemNameCreate.GetComponent<Text>().text;
            

            this.gameObject.GetComponent<nextSetAmount>().nextButtonCelestials(true);           

            AudioListener.pause = false;
            setAllInactive(parent.transform,true);
        }
    }

     // Sets all inactive if value = true
    public void setAllInactive (Transform transform, bool value)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
            {
                if(value == true)
                {
                    child.gameObject.SetActive(!value);
                }
            }       
    } 
}
```

**audioManagerCreate**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class audioManagerCreate : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioMixer systemMixer;
    public Slider slider;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {   
        // Find amount of celestials in scene
    
        
        // For each celestial, assign corresponding audio mixer group based on celestialID/i (essentially the same value)
        for(int i = 0; i < slider.value; i++)
        {
            GameObject celestialObject = GameObject.Find("celestialObject"+i).gameObject;
            string masterMix = "Master";

            celestialObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().outputAudioMixerGroup = systemMixer.FindMatchingGroups(masterMix)[i+1];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not the best at troubleshooting, but I assume that the problem exists because it cannot find the gameObject that GameObject.Find() is pointing to. It works completely fine in Unity and finds the objects without fault.

The only constant that I can see is that I'm trying to find an object based on its name + i where i is the for-int loop ID. I need to do this because its looking for objects that don't exist until they're are instantiated, and whose names are based on their ID from the for-int loop in their instantiation script.

Comment: Well you have alot of `GameObject.find()` which I would recommend avoiding as it becomes REALLY expensive, however you are doing it in a start method(Which is one of your errors), and there is no guarantee that the object you are looking for exists yet.

Comment: You may need an entry in link.xml to stop your class from being stripped.

Comment: Your problem line seems to be `this.gameObject.GetComponent<nextSetAmount>().nextButtonCelestials(true);` very probably `this.gameObject` has no component `nextButtonCelestials`. You should always make it sure by using the tag `[RequireComponent(typeof(nextButtonCelestials))]` on you class `celestialDialogueInstantiator`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a very similar problem and it was driving me crazy, since there was no sense on the fact that **GameObject.Find** was working pretty well on Simulator, but returning a NullReferenceException on iOS build. I had tried a lot of things and I had no success at all...

Then, I got an insight... the problem wasn't **GameObject.Find** method itself and I explain you why:

When we are about to generate a build in Build Settings, we need to include the Scenes we want to add to the build. Look at the picture below:

[image]

That is, **SpaceScene** scene was being executed on the code, but it wasn't included in the build... so its objects had not been loaded (of course). That's why **GameObject.Find** was returning null.

My solution was to include the scene **SpaceScene** in the build and everything ran as it was supposed to be.